# Java Observablelist copy

Tags: java, list, observablelist

I've a List of ObservableLists that I want to clone, but in a such way, that if I adjust data in cloned List, it wouldn't change data on the main List.

```
public static List <ObservableList<Person>> mainData = 
        new ArrayList<ObservableList<Person>> (FXCollections.observableArrayList());

List <ObservableList<Person>> tempData = 
            new ArrayList<ObservableList<Person>>(FXCollections.observableArrayList(familiesData));
```

Whenever I call

```
tempData.get(0).remove(0);
```

It also removes data from mainData List. I can't quite understand why it doesn't work.

Comment: Could you post a simple reproducing example that we could run?